# How can I remove power seat without battery/power?

Tags: car, seat-cars

How can I remove golf mk7.5 power seats if they are not functioning? (the sunroof broke and then it rained and due to water under seat the electronics stop working which I can't move seat forward to remove back nuts so that i can remove seat) please Any help will do

Answer (score 1):

Find the wires that connect to the relevant motor and power them direct.

I suggest you use an inline fuse as well.

**Make sure** you keep your fingers clear when it moves.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the bolts/screws that hold them to the floor.